# Angular JS. My output should give Hello but it is showing {{message}}

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new and started practicing Angular JS.

My output should give **Hello** but it is showing **{{message}}**

Below is HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="HelloWorldApp">
<head>
    <script     src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hello_world_controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="HelloWorldApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is Angular js code:

```
angular.module('HelloWorldApp', [])
  .controller("HelloWorldController", ["$scope", function ($scope){
     $scope.message = "Hello";
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any error with your code, Check your angular version

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('HelloWorldApp', []) .controller("HelloWorldController", ["$scope", function ($scope) { $scope.message = "Hello"; }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="HelloWorldApp">
 <head>
      <script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="hello_world_controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="HelloWorldApp">
<div ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still getting output as {{message}}

Comment: in script source, do I need to give the name of my js file or src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"?

Comment: chekc the attached demo and see

Comment: Sajeetharan, is something wrong with js file? please check

Comment: @SandeepKumat no you are doing something wrong, do you have team viewer?

Comment: ya sure send me the id and password

Comment: I am sending,,,

Comment: Hi do you connect agian?

Comment: hi why did you close

Comment: i did it,,,,,,,

Comment: Hi sajeetharan, I got the same problem. can you help me?